# Count number of unique names in one column compared to another - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula which would show me a total number of unique names in a column compared to another.

Example:

In column A I have a list of names
In column B I have another list of names

Some of the names in A are also in B and I want to count the number of names in A that are NOT in B. I am only looking for a number.

Make it a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small solution that will give the number of names in Column A that are not in column B.

> =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A1:A7)>0,IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A7,B1:B7,0),1),0), IF(LEN(A1:A7)>0,IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A7,B1:B7,0),1),0))>0,0,1))

you can substitute your own ranges in as needed.

you can learn more about counting unique occurrences from here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

The small modification to the link formula is instead of counting "TRUE" as 1, we count "FALSE" as 1

The only downside to this formula is that it doesn't work in cases where there are duplicate names in column A